# What is the best way to add regular widgets on top of a QGraphicsView?

Tags: python, qt, qgraphicsview

I'm researching refactoring a tkinter app that currently uses tkinter.Canvas. The Canvas reacts to user input by creating windows over the canvas, which are made of regular tkinter widgets.

I haven't seen the equivalent method in QGraphicsView to tkinter.Canvas.create_window, wihch creates a canvas bound item that can then be used for building a regular interface.

Basically I'm looking for the right way to, say, right click on the View and get a popup window on top that I can deal with. Hopefully not bound to the scene, either, so that if I have multiple views on the scene the window only appears over the original View.

Because I'm new to Qt I'm out of my depth. Perhaps the widget that contains the View can receive the clicking event and proceeds to layout another widget in absolute terms over the QGraphicsView?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear. Why not provide an example screenshot? Anyway it seems you want to create a context menu(popup menu). Then see [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Handling%20context%20menus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found how to do it:

```py
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsWidget,
)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

scene = QGraphicsScene()
view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.resize(400, 300)

window = QGraphicsWidget(None, Qt.Window)
window.resize(200, 200)

scene.addItem(window)
view.setScene(scene)
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Notice that unlike tkinter although you can add a regular widget to the QGraphicsScene directly with scene.addWidget, there are some limitations.

The method scene.addWidget returns a QGraphicsProxyWidget which is what can be positioned on the scene. And the layout of these widgets are different to the ones of regular widgets.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this.  Your post states that the window is `"... Hopefully not bound to the scene, either, so that if I have multiple views on the scene the window only appears over the original View"`: the code shown most definitely *does* bind `window` to the scene rather than the view.  Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: Do you really want to embed widgets into a QGraphicsView? It will be an awful design if you are not implementing something like a widget editor such as Qt Designer.

Comment: @ralent95: What is a better way to provide context UI to the elements in the QGraphicsView? Say I click on an element and I want a draggable dialog to appear by that element?

Comment: @G.M. You are correct. I wasn't able to to find a way to avoid it yet. Perhaps by having those dialogs floating on top of the QGraphicsView somehow? I'm new to Qt, so I don't know how to do it.